# A color gradient app replicating Microsoft Office's features

Tags: color, images, microsoft-office

I'm fascinated by how you can choose which direction the gradient follows in Microsoft Office apps. For example, in the image I've attached, the one in the middle grows in an outward direction.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Nearly all graphic design software has such features, but with a lot more control and complexity than anything available in MS Office.  If you are looking for alternatives to MS Office, try LibreOffice (which is free), or some other office suites.

Comment: Something small? Cheap?